# How can I enable retina mode in Photoshop on a Macbook Pro?

Tags: photoshop

Can you help me please. I have Macbook pro retina 15 and photoshop 13.1, I open my last project and in 100% zoom all good but very small. In 200% so blur, how can i imitate my last resolution or enable retina mode in new photoshop, thanks!

Comment: What size and resolution is the image you are opening?

Comment: To be clear: at 200% you find the image looks worse than it should when viewed larger-than-life?

Comment: I'm having the same problem; I got the retina update, but older projects are opening 100%, but at *half* the size.

Answer (score 7):

Your current version is 13.0.1 (not 13.1) and retina mode is [introduced in 13.0.2](http://gizmodo.com/5967371/adobe-photoshop-and-illustrator-now-available-with-retina-support). This should be available now via Adobe Update. You don't need to do anything to enable retina mode: it'll just work once you've updated.